# COREDATA: Add add values to one to many releationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have a coredata project:

[image]

Here I have 3 entities: a)categories, b)content, c) tags. I have already add it the categories values but I can not figure out how to set the category in the content entity when the user has selected the category where he wants the content.

I'll really appreciate you help

Comment: Content <-> Category should be many-to-many relationship in case if you want to assing multiple categories to single content. Same for tags. Besides in CoreData you name entities in singular, e.g. Categories should be Category. Then when you have relationship, each Category will have contents (many) and each content will have "Categories" and "Tags" (many again). You need the inverse relationship which will allow you to fetch all content for particular category. All of this can be set in right sidebar of CoreData entity properties for relationship field.

Comment: @Andy, In case of the Category I only need a single category per content. I'm not sure what you mean "You need the inverse relationship which will allow you to fetch all content for particular category.". Can you please provide and example?

Comment: [yourContent setValue:yourCategory forKey:@"category]!?!

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad, I tried and doesn't work

Comment: If you have the relationship set up properly, then you use the accessor methods that are dynamically created for you (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW1)

Your content CoreData object would have a method similar to `- (void)setCategory:(Category *)category;` - you just need to declare it so it's accessible

Comment: @MikeWelsh I have the categories already set my problem is add the content to the categories

Comment: If the relationship is bi-directional (as your image above indicates), it should be automatic

Comment: Set content <-> category as one-to-one relationship, setup inverse flag and you're all set.

Comment: @user2924482 You tried what exactly and what happened exactly? Do you want to say that `-setValue:forKey:` does not work? It does.

Comment: Show the code you've tried and explain what happened.

Answer (score 0):

I figure out how to add the category to the content:

```
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *contentDescription = [ NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Categories" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    NSFetchRequest *categoRequest = [NSFetchRequest new];
    categoRequest.entity = contentDescription;
    NSPredicate *categoPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category like %@", _dropMenuOulet.stringValue];
    categoRequest.predicate = categoPredicate;

    NSArray *results = [moc executeFetchRequest:categoRequest error:&error];



    Categories *catego = (Categories*) [results objectAtIndex:0];
Content *content1 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Content" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

    content1.category = catego;
    content1.title = _titleOutlet.stringValue;
    content1.body = _bodyOutlet.stringValue;
```

But now I'm trying to figure out how to add the tags to the content.